# Injecting list of strings in Guice

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to inject one arraylist of Strings in Guice. For that I am trying to construct list as following in module, which I can inject later into any class:

```
Multibinder<String> myList =
            Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), String.class);


myList.addBinding().to("Test1");
myList.addBinding().to("Test2");
```

In the above line I am getting following error:

```
The method to(Class<? extends String>) in the type LinkedBindingBuilder<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

In this context, I have found this: [Guice : Inject an ArrayList of Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802384/guice-inject-an-arraylist-of-strings), but I think given solution does not fit my use case.

Comment: Where's your arraylist? What are you trying to inject it into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.toInstance()`

```
myList.addBinding().toInstance("Test1");
myList.addBinding().toInstance("Test2");`
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older post, but I've been unsuccessful at finding a solution until today.  I've wanted to inject a list of comma-delimited strings defined in a property file in a generic way without having to explicitly create @Named providers for every property that needed to be represented as a list of Strings.

Today I found this post ([Injecting a List of Strings From a Properties File Using Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393266/injecting-a-list-of-strings-from-a-properties-file-using-guice)).  The relevant part for me was this line in my configure method:

```
 @Override 
 protected void configure() {
    ...

    binder().convertToTypes(Matchers.only(new TypeLiteral<List<String>>() {
    }), (String value, TypeLiteral<?> toType) -> Arrays.asList(value.split(",")));

    ...
 }
```

I didn't use DefaultListDelimiterHandler as the original solution did, but instead just did a standard string split converted to a List.  Now from a property file, I can have something like:

```
testList=one,two,three
```

And I can inject it using:

```
@Inject
@Named("testList")
List<String> testList;
```