# Injecting a List of Strings From a Properties File Using Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, collections, properties, guice

I have an application that needs to read in some configuration values from a Properties file and then inject those values using the @Named annotation of Guice. I'm currently doing something like this in my module:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    try {
        Properties properties = getProperties();
        Names.bindProperties(binder(), properties);
        binder().bind(MyApi.class);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

then in my application I do something like:

```
public class MyApi
{
    @Inject
    @Named("ftp.dir")
    public String ftpDirectory;
}
```

That approach works fine for injecting primitive values, but now I need to inject a List of Strings. If I just add the injection

```
@Inject
@Named("mail.to")
public List<String> mailTo;
```

for a properties file like:

```
#Properties
ftp.dir=/opt/my/dir
mail.to=foo@bar.com, abc@123.com
```

Then guice will throw an exception saying

> 'no implementation for java.util.List<java.lang.String> annotated with
> @google.inject.name.Named(value=mail.to) was bound'.

I have seen some other similar questions such as:
[Guice : Inject an ArrayList of Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802384/guice-inject-an-arraylist-of-strings)
and [Injecting list of strings in Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698033/injecting-list-of-strings-in-guice)
but all the solutions take the approach of adding an explicit binding for the field.

Is there any way to deal with collections in guice without having to manually extract them from the properties file and add an explicit binding?

Comment: Can you include the `.properties` file?

Comment: @GeorgeZ. I edited the post to include an example of the properties

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution that meets meets my needs. Guice 3.0 has a method for adding custom type converters via the Binder.convertToTypes() method. I simply called this method and passed in an implementation of com.google.inject.spi.TypeConverter that would take the property value and convert it from a String to a List. The configure method in my module ended up looking like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    try {
        //I'm using apache commons-configurations here but you could
        //just as easily use just a java Properties object
        Configuration properties = getProperties();
 
        //I'm using the builtin Matchers.only from guice for this simple 
        //case but you could implement a custom Matcher for more complex
        //behavior
        binder().convertToTypes(Matchers.only(new TypeLiteral<List<String>>(){}),
     new TypeConverter() {
            //again, I'm using commons-configuration to perform the 
            //actual conversion but you could use a different library
            //or even do the conversion yourself if needed
            final DefaultListDelimiterHandler handler = new DefaultListDelimiterHandler(',');
            @Override
            public Collection<String> convert(String value, TypeLiteral<?> toType) {
                
                return handler.split(value, true);
            }
        });

        //now that guice has a converter registered for List<String>
        //we can simply use bindProperties to set up the Named bindings
        Names.bindProperties(binder(), ConfigurationConverter.getProperties( properties));
        binder().bind(MyApi.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The advantage to this solution is that it reduces the coupling between my .properties file and the actual code. If I wanted to add additional properties with List values, I can simply change the properties file without needing to add a custom provider method for each new property. The only coupling between my code and the properties file is in the @Named annotation.

There may be a better solution to this; if you have something let me know. If going to leave this open for a few more days in case anyone has a better suggestion.

Comment: I've been wanting to find something like this for a while.  Thanks for posting, it worked great for me!

Answer (score 0):

What if you add this method to your module?

```
@Named("mail.to") List<String> provideMailtoAsList(@Named("mail.to") String mailto) {
  return List.of(mailto.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*"));
}
```

This transform the known `String` named "mail.to" into a `List<String>` that happens to also be named "mail.to".

Comment: Adding a provider method is an option, in fact that is the work around I'm using until I can come up with something better. The question though is whether there is way way to do this without having to set up a separate provider for every property that contains a list.

Comment: No, it's not possible without using this (which doesn't seem like a workaround to me). The reason is that you possibly want a comma as separator, but what if others want a dash as separator or a pipe, or a semicolon? Also, how do people know whether the spaces are important or not? So no, it's not possible because there are too many possibilites. So just use what is possible, and that's the solution I'm offering above.